create migrations with alembic
I am facing an issue when trying to generate migrations using Alembic and SQLAlchemy. My project is structured as follows:

I have a folder called model where each entity (model) is defined in a separate file.

I use a config folder containing a file called register.py, where I initialize an instance of registry() and store it in a variable named table_register.

In my models, I use the @table_register.mapped_as_data_class decorator to map the classes to database tables.


The problem occurs when I run the command:
The revision file is generated, but both the upgrade and downgrade functions are empty. It seems that Alembic is not detecting the tables mapped in my project.
register.py file:
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry

table_register = registry()

metadata = table_register.metadata

Example model:
from enum import Enum

from datetime import datetime

import sqlalchemy

from sqlalchemy import (String, func, ForeignKey)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (Mapped, mapped_column)

from configs.register import table_register

@table_register.mapped_as_dataclass
class Aluno():
    __tablename__ = 'aluno'
    
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, init=False, name='id_aluno')
    nome: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False, name='nome_aluno')
    serie: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('serie.id_serie'), nullable=False, name='serie_aluno')
    turma: Mapped[Enum] = mapped_column(sqlalchemy.Enum('A', 'B', name='turma_enum'), nullable=False, name='turma_aluno')
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(name='created_at', server_default=func.now(), init=False)    

Alembic Config:
config = context.config
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', Config().DB_URI)

target_metadata = table_register.metadata

def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section, {}),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, 
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            compare_type=True
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()

Even though everything seems to be configured correctly, Alembic does not detect the tables and generates empty migrations. I am unsure if I am missing something in the Alembic configuration or if there is a specific requirement for using SQLAlchemy's registry().
What could be causing this issue? Is there any additional configuration needed to make Alembic recognize tables defined using registry.mapped_as_data_class?

Is table_register imported into the alembic config in such a way that the tables ahve been register with it when it is imported?

What command are you running to generate the migration?

@snakecharmerb I only import the variable, something like:
from configs.register import table_register, and pass
target_metadata = table_register.metadata

@MatsLindh i run, alembic revision --autogenerate -m "revision name"

@jaspionU2 So where are you importing the models in your alembic environment? If the models never gets imported, nothing gets registered on the metadata (i.e. the code doesn't run).

@MatsLindh I just imported the table_register variable into the environment. Then it is necessary to import each model into the alembic environment? something like:
from models.Model_Aluno import aluno.

Yes, otherwise the code that registers your models never run, so Alembic has no way of detecting them. But you don't have to import the actual model, as long as you import the module / file they're stored in (so that the code runs).

@MatsLindh I imported the models into the alembic environment, using from models import *, and ran the command: alembic revision --autogenerate, but this error occurred:
File "/home/yupa_lulinha/Documentos/Estoque_QRCode/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3193, in _resolve_column     raise exc.NoReferencedTableError( sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'equipamento.id_categoria' could not find table 'categoria' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id_categoria'

That sounds like an SQLAlchemy issue, where your table and column name is different from what you've given in the foreign key construct (i.e. what the foreign key is pointing to). Since you haven't included those models in your question, it's hard for anyone else to say anything more useful.

@MatsLindh This is my mistake, I forgot to add the import of the equipment model into the alembic environment, i fix and the migration work.

I had this same issue a couple years ago when first using alembic. Now I do not remember the exact solution but this is my config.
alembic/env.py
from os import getenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

import sys
import os.path
# append parent dir to path to expose imports
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)))

# db.py
from db import DB_BASE

from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

config = context.config

uri = getenv('DATABASE_URI')
if uri.startswith('postgres://'):
    uri = uri.replace('postgres://', 'postgresql://', 1)
config.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", uri)

fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

target_metadata = DB_BASE.metadata

def run_migrations_offline():
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
        render_as_batch=True,
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()

db.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

uri = "YOUR_URI"

DB_ENGINE = create_engine(uri)
DB_SES_LOCAL = sessionmaker(bind=DB_ENGINE, autoflush=False)
DB_BASE = declarative_base()

from models import *

DB_BASE.metadata.create_all(DB_ENGINE)


sorry if i dont understand right, but the line:
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)))
Is it to recognize models?

No, that is just to use imports from the parent dir. I will edit my answer to include db/__init__.py so you can see how I define the connection and "recognize" models.

Can you tell me if it is possible to make the alembic recognize changes in type?
Because when I make this type of change, the alembic doesn't seem to recognize it.
